# return self.func(*args) TypeError: menu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I keep getting this error and I cant seem to fix it, if anybody could help me I would really appreciate it. I have been looking at it for quite a while now and I can't seem to get my head around it, I am still quite new to programming in an Object Oriented Way.

Thanks & Merry Christmas

*Welcome Page*

```
from External_Menu import *
from tkinter import *


class Welcome(Frame):

def __init__(self, root):
    Frame.__init__(self, root)
    self.welcome_button()
    self.pack()

def welcome_button(self):
    self.welcome = Button(self, text="Welcome!", command=ExternalMenu.menu)
    self.welcome.pack()
    self.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main = Welcome(root)
    main.mainloop()
```

*External Menu*

```
from tkinter import *

class ExternalMenu(Frame):

def __init__(self, root):
    Frame.__init__(self, root)
    self.menu()
    self.pack()

def menu(self):
    self.external_menu_lbl = Label(self, text="External Menu", font=("", 26))
    self.external_menu_lbl.pack()

    self.sign_in_button = Button(self, text="Sign In")
    self.sign_in_button.pack()

    self.sign_up_button = Button(self, text="Sign Up")
    self.sign_up_button.pack()

    self.pack()
```

Comment: Not versed with `tkinter` but the error is telling you that `ExternalMenu.menu` isn't getting the `self` instance argument passed to it. This is cause by you passing `command=ExternalMenu.menu` instead of `command=ExternalMenu().menu`. The first passes the function `menu` while the second the *method* `menu`.

Comment: There can be a couple of solutions to this depending on how you expect your program to work. Please provide what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Nae I would like for the "Welcome!" button to redirect to the "External_Menu", without opening a new window, I would like it within the same window if you know what I mean.

Comment: Also `self` refers to that particular instance of the class you define. So you calling `self.pack()` twice under same class with methods you call are redundant.

Comment: @AJE Your code isn't at all looking like that is what you want though. I'll provide a quick solution and then provide exactly what you need.

Comment: @Nae So what self.pack do I remove?

Comment: @AJE That is up to your choices. I'd remove the ones under methods, but that _may be_ what you want in another program.

Comment: @Nae Good thinking. I have done it already.

Answer (score 0):

Your `menu` is a *method* so it needs an object it can manipulate in order to work. But you're trying to call it without an object created for it, essentially you're calling it like a function. First you need to create an object of the class that method is defined on:

```
an_ex_men = ExternalMenu(root)
```

and then you are able to call `menu` method on `an_ex_men`:

```
an_ex_men.menu()
```

But since you already call `menu` under your `ExternalMenu`'s `__int__` method it is called as soon as an object instance for that class is created. Shortly, you creating an `ExternalMenu` object is enough to achieve that as in, even without putting it to a variable to refer later:

```
ExternalMenu(root)
```

Since you want to swap between two windows you need an additional method to either hide or completely destroy the other window. Let's say you want to destroy the other window, and for that you could use a method defined for your button that does those 2 actions:

```
def welcome(self):
    self.destroy()
    ExternalMenu(root)
```

As in:

```
...

    def welcome_button(self):
        self.welcome = Button(self, text="Welcome!", command=self.welcome)
        self.welcome.pack()

    def welcome(self):
        self.destroy()
        ExternalMenu(root)

...
```

---

Below example does exactly what you expect, first I created a parent class `App` as according to you the two frames you have are in the same level of hierarchy and having a parent for them is in my opinion better structured:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.welcome_frame = Welcome(self)
        #I believe it's better to call geometry managers as parent
        self.welcome_frame.pack()

        #assigning parent method as button command as it affects siblings
        self.welcome_frame.button['command'] = self.go_ex_men

    def go_ex_men(self):
        self.welcome_frame.destroy()
        self.ex_men = ExternalMenu(self)
        self.ex_men.pack()


class Welcome(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Welcome!")
        self.button.pack()


class ExternalMenu(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.external_menu_lbl = tk.Label(self, text="External Menu", font=("", 26))
        self.external_menu_lbl.pack()

        self.sign_in_button = tk.Button(self, text="Sign In")
        self.sign_in_button.pack()

        self.sign_up_button = tk.Button(self, text="Sign Up")
        self.sign_up_button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is a really good idea, I have implemented it within my program and I get an error " + self._options(cnf, kw)) _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!welcome"

Comment: @AJE I am not sure what that supposed to mean, but know that I only worked with a single file.

Comment: I really like how you have set out the program, how would I go about adding a new page? What confuses me is the parent class and parent method.

Comment: @AJE But that's the thing now that you want to add a new page you just need to customize it as a new class like we did with `ExternalMenu` and `Welcome` then call it the way we want in parent `App` just like we call `self.welcome_frame = Welcome(self)`. You could instead use a method that you define for `Welcome` but I think that would be messier.

Comment: Can you show me? because I am pretty confused in certain aspects.

Comment: @AJE I'm sorry but I don't want to leave the scope of the initial question any further. Basically c/p `Window` rename it and create it as another attribute inside `App` say `self.a_new_page = ANewPage(self)`.